# SQL query not showing more than 1 row

Tags: php, sql

This is the entire code the error must be in query 3 or 4. As you can see query 3 just gets info to build query 4 which should return the results.

I've got query 1 & 2 working ok which have the correct data showing.

```
<?php
session_start();
//printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($_SESSION, true));
require('includes/config.inc.php');
require('includes/session.php');

//WORKING
DB_Connect();
$query = "SELECT * FROM food_delivery_orders_items WHERE food_delivery_orders_items.type = 'product' AND food_delivery_orders_items.order_id=".$_SESSION['pdf_quote']['id']."";

$result = mysql_query( $query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
         $hash = $row['hash'];
         $foreignid = $row['foreign_id'];
          $qty = $row['cnt'];                   
            }


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM food_delivery_products WHERE food_delivery_products.id = ".$foreignid."";

$result2 = mysql_query( $query2) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
            {
         $name = $row['name'];
         $description = $row['description'];                
            }



    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM food_delivery_orders_items WHERE food_delivery_orders_items.type = 'extra' AND food_delivery_orders_items.order_id=".$_SESSION['pdf_quote']['id']."";

$result3 = mysql_query( $query3)or die(mysql_error()) ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
            {

         $foreignidextra = $row['foreign_id'];  
         $qtyextra = $row['cnt'];           

            }


            $query4 = "SELECT * FROM food_delivery_extras WHERE food_delivery_extras.id = ".$foreignidextra."";

$result4 = mysql_query( $query4) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) 

            {
         $nameextra = $row['name'];

            }

    echo $nameextra;
    echo $qtyextra;

DB_Disconnect();





//$products = implode(", ",$_SESSION['pdf_quote']['product_arr']);;

//print $products
?>
```

Comment: or that you're not only overwriting those 2 variables in the loop, but you're then printing $row after the loop concludes

Comment: have you try to debug it using `var_dump($result3)` ?

Answer (score 1):

`print $row;`  is only valid inside the loop if you want to print all of them. Otherwise it will print only the last `$row`. Make it

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
{
    $foreignidextra = $row['foreign_id'];   
    $qtyextra = $row['cnt'];            
    print $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its because you are printing the `$row` after  the  `while` loop gets executed

So it only prints the final result set

Use something like this instead:

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM food_delivery_orders_items WHERE food_delivery_orders_items.type = 'extra' AND food_delivery_orders_items.order_id=".$_SESSION['pdf_quote']['id']."";

$result3 = mysql_query( $query3) ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
{
    $foreignidextra = $row['foreign_id'];   
    $qtyextra = $row['cnt']; 
    print_r($row);           
}
```

you can also use the `var_dump($row);` instead of `print_r($row);`

this will output all the values stored in the `$row` array each time the loop iterates